# CSS height effect on cross-browser?

Tags: html, css

Running on Chrome displays the expected result. Running same code on Mozilla-Firefox displays unexpected result. So, what will be the solution to get the Chrome result in Mozilla-Firefox?

```css
textarea{ 
         height : 100%;
         position:absolute;
         
         }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td rowspan=4><textarea></textarea></td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td rowspan=4><textarea></textarea></td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr> 
  
  </table>
```

Comment: What are the "expected" results? What are the "unexpected" results?

Comment: _“So, what will be the solution to get the Chrome result in Mozilla-Firefox?”_ – it would probably start with not abusing tables for layout purposes, and using flexbox instead.

Comment: _@Turnip_ Run the snippet and check the result on both the browser, result displayed in Chrome is the expected one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget! **Height of an element is relative to its parent.**

You want to set the height to an element which has no information how high is height. You have to give the parent element a height. Look at this:

```css
tr, td, textarea {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td rowspan=4><textarea></textarea></td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr> 
  </table>
```

Comment: I think this is a better solution

Comment: @balapa Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the textarea to position: absolute. Tested and works on Firefox Mac.

```css
.textarea-td {
    position: relative;
}

textarea{
    height : 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box
        /* so it really takes the same height as the inputs */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td rowspan=4 class="textarea-td"><textarea></textarea></td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr> 
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Try This type of Manner styling in your table then its resolves easily ,So Please mention height and widths for your table and for its inner elements always .

```css
textarea{ height : 100%; }
td{padding-right:10px;}
```

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr height="25">
    <td><input type="text" style="width:100%;"></td>
    <td rowspan=4><textarea style="width:100%;"></textarea></td>
  </tr> 
  <tr height="25">
    <td><input type="text" style="width:100%;"></td>
  </tr> 
  <tr height="25">
    <td><input type="text" style="width:100%;"></td>
  </tr> 
  <tr height="25">
    <td><input type="text" style="width:100%;"></td>
  </tr> 
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a hack, but you can use position absolute to the textarea, so it can set its height to 100%.

```css
.textarea-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

textarea{
  height : 100%;
  /* firefox fix */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td class="textarea-wrapper" rowspan=4><textarea></textarea></td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr> 
  </table>
```